# Can I still submit my work to a journal if a very similar paper was just posted on arXiv?

Tags: publications, paper-submission, plagiarism, arxiv

I am from an engineering field (EE, specifically signal processing), and I have been working on a paper since March 2014.

Back then, I spent a significant amount of time reviewing the literature and didn't find any existing work that discussed my topic. I actually finished the bulk of the paper several months ago (Jan 2015), but since then I have been editing and reviewing it with my coauthors before we planned to submit to journals.

I recently, however, found a similar paper that was "published" or posted on arXiv in April 2015. I believe that it is extremely similar (~80% of the ideas). I am not sure how much of an issue this is, as I have heard that arXiv is not a "legitimate" domain (in my field, almost everyone just uses the IEEE searching engine).

My original plan was to submit my work to journals soon. Do you think I can still submit my paper to a journal? How should I acknowledge of otherwise handle the existence of this similar arXiv publication?

Comment: _But I need to wait 5 more months until my reviewers finish the reviewing process before submiting to public journal._ — Who are these reviewers you mentioned? Your co-authors?

Comment: This, right here, is a primary example of why using arXiv is highly encouraged, regardless of its "domain"

Comment: _in my field, almost everyone justs the IEEE searching engine_ — Trust me, everyone in your field uses Google.

Comment: @MadJack, I think they are co-authors....

Comment: I don't understand - what is this "reviewing process", if it's not the review process for a journal/conference submission?  Why does it take 10 months?

Comment: *Oooh, yeah, I'm going to use search tool X that requires a login and restricts my results to those from one publisher.  Way better than Google Scholar.*

Comment: @Aragon: *I think they are co-authors* – You **think** they are? Shouldn’t you know?

Comment: @Wrzlprmft: Perhaps he means that they were coauthors of the paper that scooped his work? Perhaps they delayed so that their paper would be published first?

Comment: @jvriesem: Perhaps, but there is little point in speculating about this unless the asker clarifies what review process and what similarities we are talking about.

Comment: As the original author has not yet returned to clarify, I went ahead and made some changes to the question, which included a bit of a guess at the original asker's intent in order to create what I hope is an answerable question.

Comment: This kind of thing has happened *a lot* in mathematics over the years. Very similar ideas published within months of each other, even ideas which started new areas of math. Discuss the other work, how it relates to yours and how it differs from yours and you might be okay. Have you given a talk on this work that can show you definitely came up with the idea and explored it before the other work was put on arXiv?

Comment: nothing to prove my work is the earliest, but I did sent my work for peer revision in my email. Do you think email record counts?

Answer (score 8):

Sure, you can go ahead and submit your paper. Of course you are obligated to discuss the arXiv paper, and its relation to your work -- but it sounds like you can honestly describe it as independent work. It would be a good idea to also make your paper public at this point (perhaps by posting a preprint on arXiv).